# What do Nietzsche's bogeymen say about the meaning of life?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism, meaning-of-life

What do Nietzsche's bogeymen say about the meaning of life?

Specifically, is it characteristic of his "last men" to be unconcerned whether their happiness is meaningful, or even embrace the meaninglessness of their life?

Comment: “Sisyphus… [what] was to constitute his torture at the same time crowns his victory”. camus, suggesting that it's the meaninglessness that makes us happy?

Comment: I can't help with Nietzsche, haven't read him, burbfor Camus: yes, embracing the inevitable absurdity of life was its only cure, as anti-venom is made from venom. Turning the tables on the gods who have trapped us. A big one-finger salute to the meaninglessness of the universe.

Comment: @DanBron great, thanks. about to be deleted, so thanks for the comments and answers :)